# What can be the possible solution to ImportError: No module named '[{"isInventoryOperationEnable":1'?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, web-api-testing

I'm trying to convert a Response data string to a dictionary in Robot Framework:

```
Create Session  Get_Inventory_Details   ${Base_URL}         
${Headers}= Create Dictionary   Content-Type=application/json   Authorization=bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6InByaXRpc3dhaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1Njc1MTQ2NDd9.o3qTPbj2KH6AgHpIf1BLV5nOlGL-fR83wSGAYyuWsBQ      
${Response}=    Get Request Get_Inventory_Details   inventorybyOutlet/7 headers=${Headers}  
Log To Console  ${Response.status_code}             
Log Many    ${Response.content}             
${actual_response}= Convert To String   ${Response.status_code}         
Should Be Equal ${actual_response}  200         
${Get_response}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${Response.content}''')   '${Response.content}'.replace(' ','_')
```

Getting Error on running this code:

```
ImportError: No module named '[{"isInventoryOperationEnable":1
```

[Screenshot of RobotFramework TestCase Log with Failed Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt08r.png)

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

When you call [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate), it expects that its second argument is a list of one or more Python modules. It seems pretty clear that `'${Response.content}'.replace(' ','_')` is not a valid list of modules.

I don't know why you're trying to pass the value to [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) twice. You should only pass it once.

```
${Get_response}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${Response.content}''')
```

Or, if it complains that it doesn't know about the `json` module, then

```
${Get_response}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${Response.content}''')  json
```

Comment: I do agree with your point and i had tried with ```${Get_response}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${Response.content}''')  json``` but got the following error **ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 24654 (char 24653)** So had to pass the value to **Evaluate** twice